# Mutability in functional programming

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, haskell, functional-programming

First I am a Haskell newbie.
I've read this:
[Immutable functional objects in highly mutable domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166379/immutable-functional-objects-in-highly-mutable-domain)
And my question is nearly the same -- how to efficiently write algorithms where the state is supposed to change. Let's take for example Dijkstra's algorithm. There will be new paths found and distances should be updated. And in traditional languages this is simple while in Haskell for example I can only think of creating entirely new distances which will be too slow and memory consuming. Are there something like design patterns for such cases where one should implement algorithm with mutable data structure and speed and memory usage are main concerns?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are of course many ways functional languages address this issue.

1. Different data structures - many data structures can be implemented in a *purely functional* manner, with the same algorithmic complexity as imperative versions.  Probably the most well-known work in this area is Chris Okasaki's [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.eecs.usma.edu/webs/people/okasaki/pubs.html), but there are many other resources as well.  For Dijkstra's algorithm, [Martin Erwig](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/)'s work on [functional graphs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl) is appropriate.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999072/how-do-i-implement-graphs-and-graph-algorithms-in-a-functional-programming-langua) as well.
2. Different algorithms - some algorithms have assumptions of mutability built-in, Quicksort is an example of this.  In this case an alternative algorithm can be used that's more amenable to immutability.
3. Mutable state - every functional language can model functional state with a State monad.  Most provide other forms of mutability as well, such as Haskell's ST monad and IORef's.

Comment: Sadly, research into data structures and algorithms best suited for lazy functional immutable languages lags behind that for strict imperative mutable languages.  :-(

Answer (score 7):

The [ST Monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad/ST) lets you use mutable state internally, but present a pure external interface.

Answer (score 6):

Creating new immutable objects isn't nearly as expense as you might think, since large amounts of structural sharing can occur because the compiler KNOWS they can't change and thus can be safely shared. That said, using highly imperative algorithms with lots of mutable state in Haskell is a bit of a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

In ML derivatives (such as OCaml, SML, F#), there are "references", which can be used as mutable variables.

In Haskell, this isn't cleanly handled. State is simply not covered by the usual "purely functional" style. Pure FP languages deal with "eternal truths", and are thus not very suitable for working with "ephemeral truths" (although it can be done, definitely).

However, yes, sometimes we *need* mutable state. A language such as [ATS](http://www.ats-lang.org/) incorporates *linear* types for handling destructive updates and safe resource manipulation.